# Making Images, and text resize based on window size

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I'm designing a system for a friend who's gaming clan plays Grand Theft Auto 5 online. But I'm running into a problem. When attempting to create a "drivers license" system, none of the placements remain inside the div or in the correct area as I'm attempting to resize the window. Essentially, they don't scale with the parent DIV.

I'm not well versed in this and google really hasn't done a lot to help since this appears to be a rather specific request. I have attempted to make this work, for much longer than I care to admit before asking for help.

```css
.title {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}

.license_preview {
  background: url('https://cad.warptimegaming.com/assets/img/svg/licensebg.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.license_preview .licensenumber {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
}

.license_preview .photo {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  clear: all;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.license_preview .dob {
  padding-top: 345px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
}

.license_preview .expiry {
  padding-top: 375px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
}

.license_preview .righthand {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
}

.license_preview .righthand .name {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  clear: both;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.license_preview .righthand .address {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
}

.license_preview .righthand .details {
  padding-top: 190px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font-size: 10pt;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
}

.license_preview .righthand .details span {
  padding-right: 8px;
  clear: both;
  float: right width: 600px;
}

.license_preview .righthand .details strong {
  padding-right: 8px;
  clear: both;
  float: right width: 600px;
}

.license_preview span,
.license_preview .righthand span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
}

.signature {
  font-family: 'Homemade Apple', cursive;
  font-size: 16pt;
  padding-top: 335px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="license_preview">
  <div class="licensenumber"><strong class="title">License Number</strong> <span>123-45-6789</span></div>
  <div class="photo"><span><img src="https://cad.warptimegaming.com/assets/img/misty.png"></span></div>
  <div class="dob"><strong class="title">DOB: </strong><span>01/16/1985</span></div>
  <div class="expiry"><strong class="title">Expires: </strong><span>01/16/2019</span></div>
  <div class="righthand">
    <div class="name"><strong class="title">Name: </strong><br><span>Marishiah Q. Vezorile</span></div>
    <div class="address"><strong class="title">Address: </strong><br><span>123 Fake Street,<br>Vinewood, LS </span></div>
    <div class="details">
      <strong class="title">Eyes: </strong> <span>Brown</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong class="title">Height: </strong> <span>6'3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong class="title">Sex: </strong> <span>M</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong class="title">Class: </strong> <span>D</span><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong class="title">Donor: </strong> <span>N</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong class="title">CLR: </strong> <span>N</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="signature" style="padding-top:-10px;">
    <span class="title">Signature:</span><br> Marishiah Q. Vezorile
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the `jsFiddle` for this project:
[www.jsfiddle.net/bradjtrammell/jg7favfr/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradjtrammell/jg7favfr/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: The reason your fiddle link won't save without a code block is because it's discouraged to only post a JSFiddle. Add the code *in* the question in form of a [mcve].

Comment: Bad Google. Must've caught it on a lazy day. You should explore and understand `@media` rules first, apply responsive styles, like `img {height: auto; max-width: 100%}` and look into `flex-box` styling (you will probably need to adjust your html structure if you apply the `flex` solution)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError that is not only condescending, it is also incorrect advice.

Answer (score 0):

You may use css zoom factor however resizing the text size in small screens is not standard rather than the responsive design.

sample jquery css zoom:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css({"zoom":$(window).width()/1000});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1. The basics**

Scale the license by using CSS3, like this:

```
.license_preview {
    transform: scale(.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(.5);
    -o-transform: scale(.5);
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/r0ct28a7/

**Step 2. Some improvements**

It may be wise to set the transform origin to the top left corner, by adding this:

```
.license_preview {
    ...
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

It may also be wise to define the width and height of the license preview div, like this:

```
.license_preview {
    ...
    width: 730px; /* this was 100% */
    height: 450px;
}
```

**Step 3. The final touch**

You can let jQuery do the math for the scale factor, so it will update on resize, like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var scalefactor = ($(window).width()/780);
    if(scalefactor>1) scalefactor=1;
    $(".license_preview").css('transform','scale('+scalefactor+')');
    $(".license_preview").css('-webkit-transform','scale('+scalefactor+')');
    $(".license_preview").css('-moz-transform','scale('+scalefactor+')');
    $(".license_preview").css('-ms-transform','scale('+scalefactor+')');
    $(".license_preview").css('-o-transform','scale('+scalefactor+')');
})
```

Here is a working example (fully responsive): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGvKLg

*PS. The value 780 comes from the native width of the element plus some padding for the page.*

Comment: While I greatly appreciate the help. I can't seem to make it work using the code you've provided. I think a complete rewrite of the CSS positioning is in order, and unfortunately, I don't think I'm knowledgeable enough in positioning to accomplish what I desire to do.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you seen the working example? A complete rewrite of the CSS seems like overkill to me.

Comment: I have seen the example, the background image (license image) does scale, however the text and the placements simply just go wherever they want to. I'm designing it on a 1080p monitor, when I test it on a mobile device or say a laptop, the text is not where it should be.

Comment: This is what is should look like: 
https://ibb.co/dHoxmG

This is what it looks like on the laptop:
https://ibb.co/nJhbwG

Answer (score 0):

You could try using em or rem instead of px for your sizing which will resize elements relative to the screen size as it uses your browser's default font size

Here are some notes on using em:
https://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

As for the values to use, it may take a bit of trial and error but using em should help keep things in the div when resizing even when the screen size changes